# multiple hidden fields

Tags: php, forms, hidden-field

This is my first post, so I hope I'm doing it correctly.
This code displays several rows, and for each one there is a button that I would like
to redirect to the next form to edit the current line ID register. 
I'm using variable hidden input names that are row-specific:

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{  
 $ID_variable[$count] = "ID".$row['ID'];

 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"edit\" value=".$row['ID']."></td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";

 echo "<td><input type=\"hidden\" name=".$ID_variable[$count]." value=".$row['ID']."></td>";

 echo "</tr>";
 $count++;
}
?>
```

So, I would like to pass the hidden name value for a given row to the next form I'm working with.
There must be a really simple solution, but I'm really stucked. Thanks for your time.

Comment: More of a UI point, but have you considered using radio or select  inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use javascript/jQuery to do this. This can also be done in php way but then you need to use forms.

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{  
   $ID_variable[$count] = "ID".$row['ID'];

   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td><input onClick=\"nextForm(".$ID_variable[$count].",".$row['ID'].")\" type=\"submit\" name=\"edit\" value=".$row['ID']."></td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";

   echo "<td><input type=\"hidden\" name=".$ID_variable[$count]." value=".$row['ID'].">         </td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  $count++;
}
?>


<script language="javascript">

function nextForm(name,value) {

   document.location = document.location + "?name="+name+"&value="+value;

}

</script>
```

Comment: Kindly tick this as the correct answer. This is another way of saying thanks !! :)

Comment: It's my intention, but I don't have enough points... can't click yet. I'm sorry

Comment: No Problem. I am happy that my solution helped to certain extent in solving your problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following code that I use to show data from DB and edit/delete:

```
<table>
<?php foreach ($row as $key => $value) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $value['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value['title']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo substr($value['text'], 0, 150); ?></td>
    <td>
      <a href="row_edit.php?code=<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" title="Edit..."><img alt="" src="../libs/imgs/icons/edit.png" /></a>
      <a href="row_delete.php?code=<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" title="Edit..."><img alt="" src="../libs/imgs/icons/edit.png" /></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

I hope to be helpfull.